# My code does not work, what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, popup

I'm new to JavaScript, but I followed a really good tutorial, and I'm making a sign in pop-up form, but it doesn't work... The idea is that you have one username, and one password, if both are correct, you will redirect to a page. I lost the HTML code for the form, but with an input field, the id has to  be uName, and with the password field pWord. Here's my JavaScript code:

```
function myFunction(){

    var uName = document.getElementById("uName").value;
    var pWord = document.getElementById("pWord");


}


// This line controls the uName and pWord.

if(uName = "Admin",pWord = "Admin"){

// This line creates a pop-up with the name.

alert("Welcome " + uName);

// Need a line to redirect to a new page

// Need a line with the else statement

// Need a line to say if something if not all fields are filled


}
```

The username has to be Admin and the password Admin. If you don't enter the right combination, you have to get a message like: "Incorrect combination.".

Comment: Are you getting complete object of input pWord rather than its value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of issues:

1. You're not getting the value of the password field, but the object
2. You're not validating the credentials inside the function
3. You are assigning "Admin" to `uName` and `pWord` with a single  `=`
4. You need to use `&&` to match both tests of your if statement

*As a side note: You should never validate a login with the username and password hardcoded like this, it is always avaiable to the user, all you would need to do is right click in browser and view source to see the username and password - this login script is fine for learning how javascript works, but don't implement a login like this in the real world unless it is purely a crawler type deterrent*

`=` sets a value, `==` matches the value, `===` matches the value and type (string, object, int)

```
function myFunction(){

    var uName = document.getElementById("uName").value;
    var pWord = document.getElementById("pWord").value;

    // This line controls the uName and pWord.

    if(uName == "Admin" && pWord == "Admin"){

        // This line creates a pop-up with the name.

        alert("Welcome " + uName);

        // Need a line to redirect to a new page

        // Need a line with the else statement

        // Need a line to say if something if not all fields are filled
    }

}
```

To combat your comments

```
// Need a line to redirect to a new page
window.location.href="/pagetoredirectto.html";
```

and

```
// Need a line with the else statement
if(uName == "Admin" && pWord == "Admin"){

    alert("Welcome " + uName);

} else {

    alert( "User and Pass do not match" );

}
```

and this should go just after you get the values.. so the full code is at the bottom of this answer

```
// Need a line to say if something if not all fields are filled
if( !uName || !pWord )
{
    alert( "Enter both a username and password" );
    return;
}
```

We use a `return` here to stop the rest of the function from executing

**Full Code**

```
function myFunction(){

    var uName = document.getElementById("uName").value;
    var pWord = document.getElementById("pWord").value;

    // Need a line to say if something if not all fields are filled
    if( !uName || !pWord )
    {
        alert( "Enter both a username and password" );
        return;
    }

    // This line controls the uName and pWord.

    if(uName == "Admin" && pWord == "Admin"){

        alert("Welcome " + uName);

        window.location.href="/pagetoredirectto.html";

    } else {
        alert( "User and Pass do not match" );
    }

}
```

Comment: do you think `if(uName == "Admin",pWord == "Admin"){` will work??

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai I have already updated my answer before your comment :-)

Comment: :) fine. noticed that.

Answer (score 3):

This is assignment with [`=` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators):

```
if (uName = "Admin",pWord = "Admin") {
```

While you need comparison [`==` or `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators):

```
if (uName == "Admin" && pWord == "Admin") {
```

Also usage of the comma [`,` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) is not correct (well it is correct, but not in this place). You need logical AND `&&`.

Assignment inside of `if` check makes truthy expression ("Admin" string is truthy), making code always enter if-block.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as below and check:

```
function myFunction(){
    var uName = document.getElementById("uName").value;
    var pWord = document.getElementById("pWord").value;

    if(uName != "" && pWord != ""){ /* Ensure both fields have value */
        if(uName == "Admin" && pWord == "Admin"){
            alert("Welcome " + uName);
            /* Redirection code goes here */
        }else{
            /* If user is not Admin */
        }
    }else{
        /* Validation message goes here */
    }        
 }
```

Comment: Would you not like to explain why you've done this? instead of just saying "change to this"

Comment: It should satisfy his requirement as the question statement says.

Comment: Checking for `null` and `""` are redundant, since after you also check for `"Admin"` equality.

Comment: But what if, this code is tested in IE? And what if fields are empty?

Comment: What's wrong with IE? If field is empty its value will be `""`, it can't be `null`. But if it's `empty` the check `== "Admin"` would suffice.

Comment: And what about validation message over empty fields?

Comment: I see the point now. Basically you are distinguishing validation cases: empty fields and invalid credentials. This is another useful point. Good.

Comment: From the prospective of sample code, I observed this should be required.

Answer (score 1):

Thats it i Hope:

```js
function myFunction(){

  var uName = document.getElementById("uname").value;
  var pWord = document.getElementById("pWord").value;

  if (uName == "Admin" && pWord == "Admin") {
    // This line creates a pop-up with the name.
    alert("Welcome " + uName);
    // Need a line to redirect to a new page
    document.location = "http://www.google.de"
    
    // Need a line to say if something if not all fields are filled
  }else if (uName == "" || pWord == "") {
    alert("Fill all fields");
    
  // Need a line with the else statement
  }else{
    alert("Incorrect Combination"); 
  }
  
}
```

```html
<input id="uname"></input>
<input id="pWord"></input>

<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Login"></input>
```

Still a way to insecure Version of a login script.

If you go to debug you can see username and pass in cypher text plain insecurity.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking reference of particular whole object in var `pWord` though you intend to take only value of password field.

Also You are assigning "Admin" to `uName` and `pWord` with the single `=`. For comparison use `===` or `==` though I would recommend use of `===`.

Do this:

```
function myFunction(){
    var uName = document.getElementById("uName").value;
    var pWord = document.getElementById("pWord").value;
}
```

For redirection use

```
window.location = "http://www.location.com/ie.htm";
```

Answer (score 0):

Well try this example:

```
function myFunction(){
    var uName = document.getElementById("uName").value;
    var pWord = document.getElementById("pWord").value;

    // This line controls the uName and pWord.
    if(uName == "Admin" && pWord == "Admin"){
        // This line creates a pop-up with the name.
        alert("Welcome " + uName);
        // Need a line to redirect to a new page
        location.href = "http://www.SOMEURL.com";
        // Need a line with the else statement
    } else {
        // Need a line to say if something if not all fields are filled
        alert("Wrong input");
    }
}
```